# element.selectedItem doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, xul, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I have the following code, which dynamically builds XUL interface and then it should set radiobutton radio3 as active radiobutton:

```
    addTab: function () {
        try {
            var tabpanels = document.getElementById("folderPropTabPanel");
            if (!tabpanels) {   // TB v2.0 beta
                var tabbox = document.getElementById("folderPropTabBox");   // This is the parent of tabpanels
                tabpanels = tabbox.childNodes[1];
            }
            var vbox1 = document.createElement('vbox');
            tabpanels.firstChild.nextSibling.appendChild(vbox1);
            var radiogroup1 = document.createElement('radiogroup');
            radiogroup1.setAttribute('id', 'radiogroup1');
            vbox1.appendChild(radiogroup1);
            var radio1 = document.createElement('radio');
            radio1.setAttribute('id', 'radio1');
            radio1.setAttribute('label', 'radio1');
            radiogroup1.appendChild(radio1);
            var radio2 = document.createElement('radio');
            radio2.setAttribute('id', 'radio2');
            radio2.setAttribute('label', 'radio2');
            radiogroup1.appendChild(radio2);
            var radio3 = document.createElement('radio');
            radio3.setAttribute('id', 'radio3');
            radio3.setAttribute('label', 'radio3');
            radiogroup1.appendChild(radio3);
            document.getElementById('radiogroup1').selectedItem = document.getElementById('radio3');
            Application.console.log(document.getElementById('radiogroup1').selectedItem.tagName);
            Application.console.log(document.getElementById('radiogroup1').selectedItem.id);
        } catch (e) {
            Application.console.log(e);
        }
    }
```

After running this code in my extension I see three radiobuttons, however I do not see dot inside third radiobutton. Additionally, I cannot select any other radiobutton using mouse. I do not see any errors in console, only two words: 'radio', 'radio3', so my code seems to work fine. Is it bug in Thunderbird, or what?

Comment: Use, //alert("Hello World!"); & look for the culprit.

Comment: Try using 'selectedItem=true' or 'selectedIndex' or 'document.getElementById('radiogroup1').checked = true';

Comment: I added _radio3.setAttribute('selected', 'true');_ and everything works fine, though in Thunderbird documentation I see that using selectedItem property is preferred.